# C# Windows Form snake

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this simple snake game, my problem is that the tails wont add when it reaches three tails.

```
namespace Snake
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool left = false, right = false;
        bool top = false, down = false;
        PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
        List<PictureBox> tails = new List<PictureBox>();
        int score = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

            if (((e.KeyChar.ToString() == "a") || (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "A"))&&(right == false))
            {
                right = false;
                top = false;
                down = false;
                left = true;

            }
            else if (((e.KeyChar.ToString() == "d") || (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "D"))&& (left == false))
            {
                top = false;
                down = false;
                left = false;
                right = true;
            }
            else if (((e.KeyChar.ToString() == "w") || (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "W"))&& (down == false))
            {
                down = false;
                left = false;
                right = false;
                top = true;
            }
            else if (((e.KeyChar.ToString() == "s") || (e.KeyChar.ToString() == "S"))&& (top == false))
            {
                top = false;
                left = false;
                right = false;
                down = true;
            }

        }



        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ticks every 1 sec
            if (pic.Location == head.Location)
            {
                score++;
                spawnFood();
                tails.Add(addTails());
            }
            sortLocation();
            if (right == true)
            {
                int r = head.Location.X + head.Height;
                head.Location = new Point(r, head.Location.Y);
            }
            else if(left == true)
            {
                int l = head.Location.X - head.Height;
                head.Location = new Point(l, head.Location.Y);
            }
            else if (top == true)
            {
                int t = head.Location.Y - head.Height;
                head.Location = new Point(head.Location.X, t);
            }
            else if (down == true)
            {
                int d = head.Location.Y + head.Height;
                head.Location = new Point(head.Location.X,d);
            }
            txtScore.Text = score.ToString();
        }

        private void sortLocation()
        {
            if (tails.Count == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < tails.Count; i++)
                {
                    tails[i].Location = tails[i-1].Location;
                }
                tails[0].Location = head.Location;
            }
        }

        private PictureBox addTails()
        {
            PictureBox tail = new PictureBox();
            tail.Name = "tail" + score.ToString();
            tail.BackColor =  Color.Black;
            tail.Width = 10;
            tail.Height = 10;
            this.Controls.Add(tail);
            return tail;
        }

        private void spawnFood()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int rndLocationX = rnd.Next(10, 50);
            int rndLocationY = rnd.Next(10, 50);
            pic.BackColor = Color.Red;
            pic.Height = 10;
            pic.Width = 10;
            this.Controls.Add(pic);
            if (rndLocationX >= 500)
            {
                rndLocationX -= 10;
            }
            if (rndLocationY >= 500)
            {
                rndLocationY -= 10;
            }
            pic.Location = new Point(rndLocationX*10,rndLocationY*10);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
            spawnFood();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the debugger?

Comment: Your add tails method needs to be on some sort of loop. It looks like it only runs one time and then the code simply passes it up on the next iteration. Perhaps add some comments so we can more easily understand what your code is doing.

Comment: thanks sir i'll try, I think the problem is from the sortLocation(); function what is does is follows the head of the snake

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 1; i < tails.Count; i++)
        {
            tails[i].Location = tails[i+1].Location; 
        }
        tails[0].Location = head.Location;
```

Are your tails there just stacked so to speak? That's another thought I might be thinking. I changed the tails[i-1] to tails [i+1]. Check if that does the trick.

Comment: I am having System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException , with the tails[i+1]

Comment: oh did you try just tails[i]

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting project.

I know this is an old question but I'm leaving this for a future reference.

```
private void sortLocation()
{
  if (tails.Count == 0)
  {

  }
  else
  {
    // I suspect the problem lies in the loop direction
    for (int i = 1; i < tails.Count; i++)
    {
      tails[i].Location = tails[i-1].Location;
    }
    tails[0].Location = head.Location;
  }
}
```

The following worked in my project

```
private void sortLocation()
{
  if (tails.Count == 0)
  {

  }
  else
  {
    // Now the loop direction is reversed
    for (int i = tails.Count-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      tails[i].Location = tails[i-1].Location;
    }
    tails[0].Location = head.Location;
  }
}
```

Imagine a row of people

---> John(2) Michael(1) Dave(0) --->

If each walks to the position of the person in front of them that makes sense that John has to move first.